# Can I output/flush data to screen while processing ajax page?

Tags: php, ajax

I need to display on my page a list of records pulled from a table. Ajax works fine (I query the database and put all the data inside a  on the main page) but if I have lots of records (say 500+) it will hang until data is fully loaded, THEN it will be sent back to the page and correctly displayed.

I would like to be able to display the records on the page while getting them, instead of being forced to wait until completion. I am trying with flush(); inside the remote (ajax) page but it still waits until full data is loaded.

This is what I currently have inside the ajax page:

At the very beginning:

```
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) { ob_end_flush(); }
 ob_implicit_flush(1);
```

Then whenever I have a echo call:

```
ob_flush();
```

Now if I load the ajax page alone... it will list the records while reading them from the database. But if I call the same page via Ajax, it will hang and send all the data at once.

Any idea?

This is the function I use to get the ajax content ('id' is the target , 'url' refers to the ajax page that runs the database query to list the records):

```
function ajax(id,url) {
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
 xmlhttp.send(null);
 document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = parseScript(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
```

Comment: try flush(); with ob_flush(); but Ajax is no streaming it anyway, you need to wait while page finish load...

Comment: Hmmm someone managed to obtain what I need, have a look at this example: http://ajaxify.com/run/streaming but I don't get the trick...

Answer (score 3):

Essentially you will need to create a loop with server-side code that outputs a Javascript function call to update the result. Those requests must be made in a parallel HTTP connection.

More detail is available here: http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming